# select Template module via GRAV Admin plugin

Tags: grav

Hi i created my first GRAV-Template with modular-pages.

Now i want to setup my Grav-Admin page fields to let the editor choose one of my module files `themes/my-theme/modular/xyz-module.html.twig` via a  select-field.

In other words, i need a select-field like the [Pages Field](https://learn.getgrav.org/forms/blueprints/fields-available#the-pages-field) but within my template-modular-files.

Answer (score 0):

In the [GRAV documentation](https://learn.getgrav.org/15/content/modular) you will find following sentences:
Modular subpages are in folders with names that begin with an underscore (`_`).

To select a modular template, i do this steps:

- Add Page (i.e. Sample)
- Set the parent page to a modular page
- Continue
- Change the folder name to **`_sample`**
- Save the page
- Now you can choose your modular Page Template

Remember to add the new modular page to `modular.md`